# Why is a PK being listed as having an included column in its index?

Tags: sql-server-2008, primary-key, indexing

I have been studying indexing using Adventureworks2008R2 and was told to run this query.

```
SELECT s.name AS SchemaName,
       OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id) AS TableOrViewName,
       i.name AS IndexName,
       c.name AS ColumnName
FROM sys.indexes AS i
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
  ON i.object_id = ic.object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
  ON ic.object_id = c.object_id
AND ic.column_id = c.column_id 
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
  ON i.object_id = o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
  ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id 
WHERE ic.is_included_column <> 0
  AND s.name <> 'sys'
ORDER BY SchemaName, TableOrViewName, i.index_id, ColumnName;
```

The output looks like this:

```
    SchemaName     TableorViewName   IndexName                          ColumnName
1   Production     Productreview     PK_ProductReview_ProductReviewID   Comments
2   Production     Productreview     IX_ ProductReview_ProductId_Name   Comments
```

I understand why it lists IX_ ProductReview_ProductId_Name but cannot make out why it shows PK_ProductReview_ProductReviewID.

The notes say by way of explanation "*All columns in a clustered index are, by definition, included already.*"
In which case why is only the Comments column shown and why aren't all PKs listed?

I suspect I am being reeeeally dumb but . . .
TIA

**--Edit**
It seeems that all PKs on a table that have a non clustered index with an included column are shown to have the same included column. 
That is the "how" answered, but I would still like the "why" answered.

Answer (score 0):

At least one of those joins conditions appears to be insufficient. Both [`sys.indexes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173760.aspx) and [`sys.index_columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175105.aspx) can define multiple indexes for the same `object_id`.

Try:

```
FROM sys.indexes AS i
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
  ON i.object_id = ic.object_id AND
    i.index_id = ic.index_id
```

In other words, I think one of the rows is a phantom produced by this incorrect join. You're seeing it because it happens to be another index on the same table.

---

And, by the way, a better way of filtering out system objects (usually) is to include [`OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id,N'IsMSShipped') = 0`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176105.aspx) in your `WHERE` clause, rather than querying the schema that an object belongs to.

Comment: **Thank you** #1 . . .
 . . . for spotting the issue.
My mistake was in blindly trusting whoever wrote the MOC training course rather than looking closely at the t-SQL code. Being near the bottom of the steep learning curve is my excuse   
**Thank you** #2 . . . 
 . . . for providing the additional advice